# iOS Pushing a ViewController not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

I've read a lot of similar questions, and I cannot figure out why the view is not working.. I've spent four hours on this, so I thought it time to ask for help.

My main VC code is a UITableView with this method at didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    svc = [[SubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubView" bundle:nil];
    //UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0 :
            switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0 :
                    NSLog(@"0");
                    svc.label.text  = @"Item";
                    break;

                case 1:
                    NSLog(@"1");
                    svc.label.text  = @"Category";
                    break;
            }
            break;
    NSLog(@"2");        
    case 1 : svc.title  = @"Second Cell"; break;
    case 2 : svc.title = @"Third Cell"; break;
    case 3 : svc.title = @"Image"; break;
    case 4 : svc.title = @"Notes"; break;
            NSLog(@"3");
            break;
    }
    NSLog(@"4");
    //svc = [[SubViewController alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"svc is %@", svc);
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubView" bundle:nil];
                        //initWithRootViewController:svc];

    [nc pushViewController:svc animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"self.navigation is as %@",nc);
    NSLog(@"5");
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

You can see whatI've tried too. The output log shows this:

```
2013-02-12 13:32:22.858 CollapsableTableView[35122:c07] -[ViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]
2013-02-12 13:32:22.859 CollapsableTableView[35122:c07] -[SubViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]
2013-02-12 13:32:22.860 CollapsableTableView[35122:c07] wtf
2013-02-12 13:32:22.860 CollapsableTableView[35122:c07] 0
2013-02-12 13:32:22.860 CollapsableTableView[35122:c07] 4
2013-02-12 13:32:22.861 CollapsableTableView[35122:c07] svc is <SubViewController: 0x10363070>
2013-02-12 13:32:22.863 CollapsableTableView[35122:c07] self.navigation is as <UINavigationController: 0x101608b0>
2013-02-12 13:32:22.863 CollapsableTableView[35122:c07] 5
```

So the SubView is being found, but not loading.. Any ideas will be valued. Thanks

UPDATE. After taking comments (THANKS:)) my code now looks like this, but still nada...

```
svc = [[SubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubView" bundle:nil];


UINavigationController *nc = self.navigationController;


switch (indexPath.section) {
case 0 :
        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0 :
                NSLog(@"0");
                svc.label.text  = @"Item";
                break;

            case 1:
                NSLog(@"1");
                svc.label.text  = @"Category";
                break;
        }
        break;
NSLog(@"2");        
case 1 : svc.title  = @"Second Cell"; break;
case 2 : svc.title = @"Third Cell"; break;
case 3 : svc.title = @"Image"; break;
case 4 : svc.title = @"Notes"; break;
        NSLog(@"3");
        break;
}
NSLog(@"4");
//svc = [[SubViewController alloc] init];

NSLog(@"svc is %@", svc);

 [nc pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
//pushViewController:svc animated:YES];

NSLog(@"self.navigation is %@",nc);
NSLog(@"5");
```

Comment: is 'SubView' is the nib file for 'SubViewController' ?

Comment: you're creating a new navigation controller instead of using the one already in view. the nav you are creating isnt visible, so it doesn't look like it pushes anything

Comment: @RenoJones: SubView is the name of the nib.

Comment: @ColdLogic. I got the same result when I simply used self.navigationcontroller. Perhaps if you add a code snippet, I can see if I've done something dumb again.

Comment: do this:    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];

Comment: @RenoJones - I got the same result as with Ryan Poolis's idea. (below)

Comment: oh apparently you need to add navigationcontroller before coming to your current screen. The screen which you are at right now. (one with tableview). Before Coming to this screen, via push on this screen or if it is the first controller, when you are adding it on window in didfinishlaunching then do this: UINavigationController *navCont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourcurrentcontrollerobject" bundle:nil]; and then pass navCont to window (if it is your first controller) or else pass navCont to the one who is pushing you to current screen. hope im clear. cheers.

Comment: ok. I'll look at that..

Comment: Wait... do you not even have a navigation controller on the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before creating this view add a navigation controller (APP DELEGATE)or such. then make this view the root for the navigation controller.

Finally. `self.navigationController pushViewController:(UIViewController*) animated:(BOOL)`
I think this will do the trick.
If you are not sure on how to add a navigation controller then search for init with root view controller for navigation controller.

But if your point is adding a new view controller here then you are correct just forgot to add  as the subview to the main view.

Answer (score 1):

```
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubView" bundle:nil];
```

replace that with:

```
UINavigationController *nc = self.navigationController;
```

You are creating a brand new `UINavigationController`. YOu need to use the one your have and push to it.

**Note**

Even if you were making a new `UINavigationController` you wouldn't do so with a view controller nib. You'd use the code you commented to set a `rootViewController` for your fresh `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I have this code now: svc = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
 
 NSLog(@"svc is %@", svc);
 UINavigationController *nc = self.navigationController;
      //initWithRootViewController:svc];
 
 [nc pushViewController:svc animated:YES]; but get this log: 2013-02-12 13:48:33.642 CollapsableTableView[35341:c07] svc is <SubViewController: 0x75323d0>
2013-02-12 13:48:33.642 CollapsableTableView[35341:c07] self.navigation is as (null)

Comment: That means you don't have a navigationController at all. You need to create one before your main VC and set your main VC as it's root.

Comment: hmm. I'm updating my question with the current code - the output log is the same as my last comment..

Comment: Is the nc still `null`? Did you create the `UINavigationController` in your `AppDelegate`?

Comment: I just did it.. Bingo!! I hope you dont mind but Prajwal Udupa gave me the exact answer (and he is newer), so I will give him the solution credit.